# Problem with API Gateway and AWS Lambda Function: Malformed Lambda proxy response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, malformed

I'm trying to make a HelloWorld using a DotNet Core Lambda Function with an API Gateway.

My lambda function is returning

```
"{\"isBase64Encoded\":false,\"statusCode\":200,\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\",\"Custom-Header\":\"application/json\"},\"body\":\"{\\u0022message\\u0022:\\u0022ola\\u0022}\"}"
```

[Aws Lambda Function Return Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWIS5.png)

But My API Gateway tells me that is a malformed response.

```
Fri May 22 16:52:12 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: "{\u0022isBase64Encoded\u0022:false,\u0022statusCode\u0022:200,\u0022headers\u0022:{\u0022Content-Type\u0022:\u0022application/json\u0022,\u0022Custom-Header\u0022:\u0022application/json\u0022},\u0022body\u0022:\u0022{\\u0022message\\u0022:\\u0022ola\\u0022}\u0022}"
Fri May 22 16:52:12 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response

Fri May 22 16:52:12 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502
```

I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after some more time researching I found the correct way to do it.

I was tring to create my own JSON string without any success. When I tried to use the APIGatewayProxyResponse object the API Gateway understood the Lambda Function's answer correctly.

Even the answer shown in the AWS Lambda Function test looks different.

[AWS Lambda Function return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BEZS.png)

To use it it's necessary to install the nuget package Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents